# How to update history dictionary attribute of a class instance and preserve order?

Tags: python, class, dictionary, updates

I am new to class programming. I am trying to save initial attributes (which are a dictionary) of my object in its history, and then update history with the changes of attributes. Below the code:

```
import datetime
import pytz

class Property:
    """ Simple property class """ 

    @staticmethod
    def _current_time():
        utc_time = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
        return pytz.utc.localize(utc_time)
    
    def __init__(self, link, attributes):
        self._link = link
        self.__attributes = attributes
        self._history = [(Property._current_time(), attributes)]
        
    def update(self, new_attributes):
        def dictdiff(d1, d2):                                              
            return dict(set(d2.items()) - set(d1.items()))
        attr_change = dictdiff(self.__attributes, new_attributes) 
        self.__attributes.update(attr_change)
        self._history.append((Property._current_time(), attr_change))
        
    def show_attributes(self):
        return self.__attributes
    
    def show_history(self):
        # how to show changes in time?
        return self._history
    

prop = Property(1234, {"Price":3000, "Active":"Yes"})
prop.update({"Price":2500, "Active":"Yes"})
prop.update({"Active":"No"})
prop.show_history()
```

And output:

```
Out[132]: 
[(datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 28, 10, 24, 19, 712385, tzinfo=<UTC>),
  {'Price': 2500, 'Active': 'No'}),
 (datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 28, 10, 24, 19, 712385, tzinfo=<UTC>),
  {'Price': 2500}),
 (datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 28, 10, 24, 19, 712385, tzinfo=<UTC>),
  {'Active': 'No'})]
```

First item in history should actually be:

```
(datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 28, 10, 24, 19, 712385, tzinfo=<UTC>),
  {"Price":3000, "Active":"Yes"})
```

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19121446/python-object-history) but without success. It seems that init function is updating history of initialization as attributes are updated, and in the meanwhile in the history at the first place I want to see attributes that were first-time initialized.

Comment: Probably a bad duplicate, but your problem is basically the same: [How to copy a dictionary and only edit the copy](//stackoverflow.com/q/2465921)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're modifying the dictionary in the history with this code:

```
self.__attributes.update(attr_change)
```

You're basically doing this:

```
>>> attributes = {}
>>> history = [attributes]
>>> attributes.update(foo=3)
>>> history
[{'foo': 3}]
```

This is easily fixed by storing a *copy* of the dictionary in the history:

```
self._history = [(Property._current_time(), attributes.copy())]
```

See also [How to copy a dictionary and only edit the copy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2465921).

Answer (score 1):

You want the *first* history entry be a *copy* of the `attributes`.

```
self._history = [(Property._current_time(), dict(attributes))]
```

As your code is now, the first history entry *references* the *current* attribute dictionary.